# Migrating from .travis CI to GITHUB action

Tags: travis-ci, github-actions, migrating

migrating to the GitHub action from Travis CI,
there is a line
'git diff --name-only "$TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE"'
but it is for Travis and while running on GitHub action not getting the value of this variable "$TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE"
what should we use instead of this variable to get the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
COMMIT_RANGE: ${{ github.event.before}}...${{ github.event.after}}
```

In github.event we have all the details so, we can use before and after to get the "$COMMIT_RANGE" same as in travis "$TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE" variable